# Android TranslateAnimation Overwrites Other Layout Views

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, translate-animation

I have a RelativeLayout (vertical) defined to include 3 Views. The top and bottom views are 16 pixels high, and display text.  The middle view displays graphics for a game application.

At various points during game play, the app runs a TranslateAnimation that effectively "scrolls" the middle view up or down.  This keeps the game character in the game "centered" in the middle view.

My problem is that when the animation runs, the translation causes the top or bottom views to be overwritten.  This lasts only for the duration of the animation.  When the animcation completes, everything is fine and the top/bottom views display their text as expected.  What is surprizing to me is that the translation animation displays content outside of the (middle) view in which it is running.  My desire is that when the translation slides the display up/down, that the animation only affects the middle view and does not obscure content in the top or bottom views.

The following is the code I am using to create the layout.  The custom views derive directly from View and display content in their onDraw(Canvas) methods.

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

topView = new MyTextView(this);
topView.setId(1);

middleView = new MyGameView(this);
middleView.setId(2);

bottomView = new MyTextView(this);
bottomView.setId(3);

final int textSize = 16;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTop = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, textSize);
lpTop.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpBottom = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, textSize);
lpBottom.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpMiddle = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lpMiddle.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
lpMiddle.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, 3);

rl.addView(topView, lpTop);
rl.addView(middleView, lpMiddle);
rl.addView(bottomView, lpBottom);

setContentView(rl);
```

The code in middleView that launches the animation is as follows:

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, yDistance);
ta.setDuration(500);
startAnimation(ta);
```

I have tried a number of things to get this animation to behave as desired, but have been unable to do so.  Hopefully someone out there can help.  Thanks in advance.